# Divisibility problem! I cannot find a proof. Help would be appreciated!

Tags: number-theory

It appears that IntegerQ[(2 k - 2^k)/(2 k + 1)] and IntegerQ[(2^k + 1)/(2 k + 1)] have the same k values. Proof?

Comment: What do you mean by "same `k` values"?

Comment: Generally the place to ask for a "proof" is math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Akku14 Note that `ForAll[{f, g}, IntegerQ[f] && IntegerQ[g], j == k]` first evaluates to `ForAll[{f, g}, False, j == k]` because the `Head` of `f` and `g` is not `Integer` and `IntegerQ` evaluates right away. I don't think your rephrasing of the problem is accurate.

Comment: The original statement was *"It appears that `IntegerQ[(2 k - 2^k)/(2 k + 1)]` and `IntegerQ[(2^k + 1)/(2 k + 1)]` have the same `k` values",* which I interpreted as *"It appears that `IntegerQ[(2 k - 2^k)/(2 k + 1)]` and `IntegerQ[(2^k + 1)/(2 k + 1)]` have the same values for all `k`".* For instance we can see `Block[{j = 0, k = 1}, IntegerQ[(2 j - 2^j)/(2 j + 1)] && IntegerQ[(2^k + 1)/(2 k + 1)]]` returns `True` for `i != j`, so the new statement seems to be wrong.

Comment: Ok. @MichaelE2 , think you are right with the understanding of the original statement. I reset it. But then proof is easy (but not directly related to MMA), since `Simplify[f+g]==1`  with `f = (2 k - 2^k)/(2 k + 1); g = (2^k + 1)/(2 k + 1); `

Comment: @Akku14 Yes, the proof is easy. And judging from Hendrick’s wonderful answers pertaining to say numerical linear algebra or performance tuning, many of which have less than five upvotes, I’d say an easy proof having nothing to do with Mma is well-received by our community. (I’m not criticizing the answer, which can hardly be improved; just being amused by SE voting patterns.)

Comment: I think this question should be reopened iff at least one answer can show how to prove such statements using mathematica. Not that the current answer isn’t great, but to fit with the subject/theme of this SE site.

Answer (score 9):

One has

$$(2 \, k - 2^k) + (2^k + 1) = 2 \, k + 1,$$

hence

$$\frac{2 \, k - 2^k}{2 \, k + 1} + \frac{2^k + 1}{2 \, k + 1} = 1,$$

thus

$$\frac{2 \, k - 2^k}{2 \, k + 1} = 1 - \frac{2^k + 1}{2 \, k + 1}.$$

So if one of the two fractions is an integer, then the other one has to be an integer, too.

Comment: If you add a *Mathematica* proof, e.g. `Reduce[Exists[{p, q}, (2 k - 2^k) == q (2 k + 1) && (2^k + 1) == p (2 k + 1)] /. 2^k -> u, {}, {u}, Integers]`, it might be worth 7 or even 8 upvotes, maybe more. :) Cheers! (I'm suggesting you could add the `Reduce[..]` code, if you think it's valid, because the question is closed. I got back home too late to post my own answer.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ha! I don't dare to do it because I just don't understand it. `Reduce` with four arguments is not documented. No idea what it is supposed to do. And why does `Reduce[Exists[{p,q}, (2 k - 2^k) == q (2 k + 1) && (2^k + 1) == p (2 k+1)], k, Integers]` not work?

Comment: I think the `Reduce` code with the `2^k` doesn't work because of the `2^k`.  In my code the problem is about polynomials, and the corresponding methods are more robust than those for nonalgebraic systems. It's also a more general problem, since `u` can be any integer and not just `2^k`, so I suspect `Reduce` does not try the substitution. -- The third argument `{u}` is [documented in V4 as `elims`](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/RefGuide/Reduce.html), dropped from V5+ docs; status uncertain, but still here, probably embedded in the system and hard to remove.

Comment: Perhaps this is a simpler, clearer solution: `sol = Solve[Eliminate[And[2 k - 2^k == q (2 k + 1), 2^k + 1 == p (2 k + 1)] /. 2^k -> u, {u}], p]` shows if one divisibility problem can be solved, so can the other. Verify with `Equivalent[2 k - 2^k == q (2 k + 1), 2^k + 1 == p (2 k + 1)] /. First[sol] // Simplify`

Comment: Or even simpler: `Reduce[(2 k - 2^k) == q (2 k + 1) && (2^k + 1) == p (2 k + 1) /. 2^k -> u, {q, p, u}, Integers]`, the result of which essentially encodes your last assertion.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thank you!